# Insert String,Float and DateTime values into sql table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have sql table named Table1 which has 3 columns - Name(string),Value(float),Date(datetime).I want to fill the table when Button1 is clicked.
So i have a function "Insert" which fills the table and button click function that gets values from two text boxes.The problem is that when i call "Insert" function like explained it gives me error messsage that some arguments are not valid

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]  
        public void Insert(string Name, float Value, DateTime DateTime)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FatherDB"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table1 ((Name) values(@Name) ,(Value) values(@Value),(Date) values(@Date))", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();                 
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              DateTime z = DateTime.Now;                   
              string Name = Box1.ToString();
              float Value = float.Parse(Box2.Text);


        Insert(Name, Value, z);
            //Insert(Name, Value, z); want to call the function with parameters from text boxes




        }
    }
}
```

Html page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <script type="text/javascript">


    </script>

    <style>
        .TBox{
            position:relative;          
            height:30px;
            width:150px;
            margin-left:10px;         
        }
        .Div {
        margin-top:50px;        
        }
    </style>

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="Div">
        <asp:TextBox id="Box1" CssClass="TBox" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>

        <asp:TextBox id="Box2" CssClass="TBox" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button id="Button1" CssClass="TBox" runat="server" Text="Enter"  />     
    </div>        

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error message exactly?

Comment: now it works without error but the table is not filled

Comment: @Arch_interpreter, make sure you are checking the right database. May be you have multiple database for development and production etc

Comment: well connection string is set properly and i have just that database
im curious whats the problem. Everytime i click the button it calls the function but when i click show table data, its empty

Comment: @Arch_interpreter, are you trying to see the data in SQL Server Management Studio ?

Comment: im using Visual Studio 2012 and its WebForms project so i can see the sql tables in Server Explorer if you know what i mean

Comment: @Arch_interpreter, may be the table is not getting refreshed in Visual studio, If you have SQL Server management studio, try in that, or restart visual studio and check your data again.

Comment: i got an error now within`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and error says ":String or binary data would be truncated."

Comment: ok finnaly its done i always make mistakes in the smallest thing i have delete the calling method from Html which calls the C# function and didnt see that :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your insert statement is wrong it should be:

```
"Insert into Table1 (Name,Value,[Date]) values(@Name, @Value,@Date)"
```

So replace this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table1 ((Name) values(@Name) ,(Value) values(@Value),(Date) values(@Date))", con))
```

with:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table1 (Name,Value,[Date]) values(@Name, @Value,@Date)", con))
```

See: [INSERT Examples (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx#BasicSyntax)

Comment: Damn you are fast. I almost hit "post your answer" button with the same content. +1

Comment: @Arch_interpreter, you are welcome, It appears that you are starting to work with ADO.Net, really good to see you are using parameters and not concatenating queries.